# Recursion: how to get all the (sub)edges for a certain node?

Tags: javascript, recursion, graph

My problem is as follows. I have an array of objects in the form of source/target from a graph (these are the id's of the node). It looks like this:

```
[{"source": 1053, "target": 845, "value": 751}, {"source": 845, "target": 862, "value": 751}, {"source": 1053, "target": 611, "value": 751}, {"source": 1053, "target": 611, "value": 751}, {"source": 1054, "target": 905, "value": 17}, {"source": 1055, "target": 837, "value": 8}, {"source": 1055, "target": 837, "value": 8}, {"source": 1055, "target": 837, "value": 8}, {"source": 1055, "target": 400, "value": 8}, {"source": 1055, "target": 400, "value": 8}, {"source": 1055, "target": 400, "value": 8}]
```

Now: For a certain node id I would like to know all its children and the subsequent subchildren of these children and so on, all the way down. It works for the first "generation", but then I would need to iterate over the targets again and again. How do I accomplish this?

```
nodes = [1053]
function getChildren(nodes, links) {
    var children = [];
    $.each(links, function(key, link) {
        if (nodes.indexOf(link.source) > -1) {
            children.push(link.target);
        }
    });
    return children;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use $.each, it only makes the function slow.

Comment: What would be a better alternative?

Comment: Does your [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) have any especial properties? Or is it just a weighted, directed graph?

Comment: a for-loop? `for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){if (nodes.indexOf(links[i].source) > -1) children.push(links[i].target); }`

Comment: @Bergi Just a weighted, directed graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion would look like:

1. Get all children of the given node
2. if one of them is new to your result array

   - get all of its children and add them
3. return the result

...which would be a simple [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

```
function getAllLinkedTo(nodes) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
        getChildren(nodes[i]);
    function getChildren(node) {
        if (result.indexOf(node) > -1)
            return;
        result.push(node);
        for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) // a source -> targets mapping object would be beneficial
            if (links[i].source == node)
                getChildren(links[i].target);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also accomplish this with a loop over `result`, which may be faster.

Comment: Could you exemplify this with this some code? I'm not sure how to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Having got the list of children for a node, just iterate over the array and for each call getChildren again. Whether you do this recursively or not depends on whether you want to go depth-first or breadth-first (see Bergi's answer).
2. Note that if you have cycles in the graph, a naive implementation will recurse forever, at least until it reaches a maximum recursion depth or stack overflow. To do this safely, you need to pass a list of nodes already seen in the hierarchy for a given node, which you check before recursing.
3. Consider creating a simpler map structure with sourcenode:targetnode as the key:value pairs, so that you can just do a lookup rather than indexOf, which will be slower.
4. If you need the lists of all children for all nodes, consider building a tree of all the nodes, otherwise you will recurse over a given node several times if it is the target of multiple edges.

Answer (score 1):

And another algorithm, a bit like the one from Phil H's answer. Its an breadth-first one, and using the helper map structure.

```
Array.prototype.combine = function(a) {
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (this.indexOf(a[i]) == -1)
            this.push(a[i]);
    return this;
};

var map; // cache
function buildMap(links) {
    return links.reduce(function(map, val) {
        if (!map[val.source])
            map[val.source] = [];
        map[val.source].push(val.target);
    }, {});
}

function getLinked(nodes) {
    if (!map)
        map = buildMap(links);
    var result = nodes.slice(0);
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
        result.combine(map[result[i]]);
    return result;
}
```